# Scala functional literals

Tags: scala, literals

1. `val x = (x:Int, y:Int) => (_:Int) + (_:Int)`
2. `val y = (_:Int) + (_:Int)`

In the above two functional literals in Scala, when I call the first one ( e.g: x(2,3) ), it is not returning the sum. Rather it returns another result, say res0. When I call res0(2,3), then it return me the sum. Whereas the second one, returns the answer in the very first call (say: y(2,3) gives me 5).

Can someone please explain why the first one does not return me the sum  (which is 5) in the first call itself.

I tried in REPL.

Comment: Hint #1: `foo => bar` is a function which takes in `foo` and returns `bar`. Hint #2: `_ + _` is a function that takes in two arguments and returns their sum (it is basically syntactic sugar for `(x, y) => x + y`, meaning whenever you see `_ + _` you can mentally replace it with `(x, y) => x + y`). Hint #3: Putting #1 and #2 together, what then is logically `foo => _ + _`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It might be helpful to write out the full types of `x` and `y` like so

```
val x: (Int, Int) => (Int, Int) => Int = 
  (a: Int, b: Int) => (_: Int) + (_: Int)

val y: (Int, Int) => Int = 
  (_: Int) + (_: Int)
```

Here we see when `x` is applied to two arguments it returns yet another function of type

```
(Int, Int) => Int
```

Note that shorthand

```
(_: Int) + (_: Int)
```

is equivalent to

```
(a: Int, b: Int) => a + b
```

Comment: Just came across a concept called currying. Is the first one is same as currying ?

Comment: @user3103957 Yes... First one is currying.

Answer (score 3):

```
val x = (x:Int, y:Int) => (_:Int) + (_:Int)
```

Is equivalent to

```
val x = (x : Int, y : Int) => ((arg1:Int, arg2:Int) => (arg1:Int) + (arg1:Int))
```

While

```
val y = (_:Int) + (_:Int)
```

Is equivalent to

```
(x:Int, y:Int) => (x:Int) + (x:Int)
```